# Project Owner Role cannot access recourses in Editor

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have created a project and have deployed two services in App Engine. I am trying to add another developer to have full access to resources in my project (including all the source code and files in App Engine). I gave him owner, admin and a few other roles but it seems he can access most of the stuff (like logs, app dashboards etc.) but not the source code of my services.

If my explanation is not clear here's some picture for further details:

1. Other original account and Editor
   [image]
2. The new account that has Owner access to the same project as above
   [image]

What am I missing and how can I give access to another developer to those projects in Editor?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is the Cloud Shell interface and it's not 'shared' across users how you seem to think it would other resources in the project. See details here: https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/how-cloud-shell-works

Essentially the other user needs to run the same steps as you to get the code to appear on their Cloud Shell instance (probably git clone and everything else). 
Alternatively you can also host your code on Cloud Source Repositories on the project and the other user should be able to access it: https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/how-to

Comment: @Tanjin, Your first link is a valuable information that was missing for me. I have a follow up question regarding your second point, if I host my code in Cloud Source Repository is it possible that all users can deploy and stop my running services?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting this answer as a Community based on the comments.

"[Cloud Shell instances](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/how-cloud-shell-works) are provisioned on a per-user, per-session basis."

In simple words, every user has his own configuration and directories in Cloud Shell.

With regards to the new question that was raised in the comments, if it is possible that all users with access to a Cloud Repository can deploy and stop your running services.

No, the users with access to your Cloud Repository, cannot deploy and stop running other resources. Even if you grant these permissions on project level, they will apply to all the Repositories in this project but not other resources.

The matrix below, describes the actions each user is able to perform on a Cloud Repository, depending on the Role he is granted:

[image: Permissions Matrix]

[Source](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/configure-access-control#roles_and_permissions_matrix)

For future reference, when a new question, not related to the Original Post is raised, kindly make a new post providing details to address it.